# Whether does Eigen comma initializer accept 0 vector?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXi a, b, aAndb;
a.resize(10);
b.resize(0);
aAndb.resize(10);    

aAndb << a, b;
```

Please read the above code. Basically, I have a vector 'a' which length is 10 and a vector 'b' which length is 0. When I use them to create aAndb, it gives me an assertion failure in CommaInitializer class destructor. However, if 'b''s length is larger than 0, there is no error. I'm using Eigen 3.2.9. Is this a correct response from Eigen or because my usage is wrong?

Comment: What does the assert message tell you?

Comment: eigen_assert(((m_row+m_currentBlockRows) == m_xpr.rows() || m_xpr.cols() == 0)
    && m_col == m_xpr.cols()&& "Too few coefficients passed to comma initializer (operator<<)");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma initializer creates side by side column.

```
// From Eigen 3.2.9
/* inserts a matrix expression in the target matrix */
template<typename OtherDerived>
CommaInitializer& operator,(const DenseBase<OtherDerived>& other)
{
  if(other.rows()==0)
  {
    m_col += other.cols();
    return *this;
  }
  ...
```

From the patch linked in Peter's answer

```
template<typename OtherDerived>
CommaInitializer& operator,(const DenseBase<OtherDerived>& other)
{
+    if(other.cols()==0 || other.rows()==0)
+      return *this;
     if (m_col==m_xpr.cols())
```

Changed in the dev branch (as well as in the 3.1 & 3.2 branches, but not in 3.2.9):

```
/* inserts a matrix expression in the target matrix */
template<typename OtherDerived>
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
CommaInitializer& operator,(const DenseBase<OtherDerived>& other)
{
    if (m_col==m_xpr.cols() && (other.cols()!=0 || other.rows()!=m_currentBlockRows))
    {
       m_row+=m_currentBlockRows;
       m_col = 0;
       m_currentBlockRows = other.rows();
       eigen_assert(m_row+m_currentBlockRows<=m_xpr.rows()
         && "Too many rows passed to comma initializer (operator<<)");
    }
```

This was addressed [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1272) (Christoph's [comment](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1272#c3)).

Answer (score 1):

Someone else before you seems to have had the same issue [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=107974). If you follow the link, there is a patch to Eigen 3.1.0 that allows you to use empty vectors in the comma initializer list. I have not tried this patch myself.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been very recently fixed in the 3.2 and devel branches. You can either wait for 3.2.10 or get the head of the 3.2 branch [there](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/downloads?tab=branches).